# How to show login screen before shell in prism 7 ? Because there is PrismApplication in app.xaml and no OnStartup() method in app.xaml.cs

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-7

I want to show login screen before shell in my prism application (prism 7) so i don't know how to do it because there is no OnStartup() method in app.xaml.cs class file where I show the login window before bootstrapper loads. 
Previously in prism 5 for login I open a login window before bootstrapper. If credentials are correct then bootstrapper loads.
Please help me out.

```
// app.xaml.cs file
public partial class App
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {

    }
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
        //return  new DirectoryModuleCatalog() {  ModulePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> there is no OnStartup() method

Says who?

Just write

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartUp(e);
}
```

within your `app.xaml.cs` and add whatever functionality you require.

Comment: I want to open login screen before shell. can you help me out with this ? I am not very much aware about prism.

Comment: Can you precisely state your problem? Your question reads like you have it working in prism 5 and hav problems porting to prism 7.

Comment: I want to show the login window before shell. If user insert correct credentials then only show shell. This is my problem.

Comment: Showing the login window? Or the `if` to not show the shell? What of this works with prism 5?

Answer (score 0):

`PrismApplication` in Prism 7 is a child of `PrismApplicationBase` which has

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e);
```

So, as stated by **Haukinger**, overriding this method and inserting your login code should work.